# Setting the screen/monitor used in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, laptop, display, tv

i am trying to get my Windows 8 laptop to connect to a TV screen. The problem is, i have got the wire connected into the TV, Windows 8 "detects" the other screen. So right, thats all good, i click on "Display on screen 2".
 My problem is, it is not Displaying on the TV screen. Even worse, i cannot see my own screen! So i am pretty much stuck with a blank screen. I am unable to see the BIOS because that too is displayed on "another screen", and i am only able to see whatever its called when you press F2 on startup.

So, how am i going to make the laptop display its info on the in-built monitor again? And once i have done that, How am i going to successfully get my computer to display to and send information to the TV screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Most laptops have a way to cycle between the various multi-screen modes using the keyboard. The getting started or user manual will include instructions on it. The screen modes are usually:

- Laptop screen only
- External screen only
- Same content mirrored on both
- Different content on both

Windows key + P will also bring up a list of modes in Windows 7 or later.

Comment: Do you know what that would be for an intel laptop running windows 8?

I am of course unable to see the screen from anything after the startup. ("Medion" screen shows with a loading thing, then screen goes blank)

Comment: Usually it's the FN key + a key with a rectangle(s) on it which is commonly one of the F1 thru F12 keys. There isn't a standard unfortunately so reading the manual for your specific laptop would be a lot quicker.

Comment: FN + Tab, FN + arrow keys, FN + page up&down unfortunatley didnt work. I'll try and find my manual, so thanks for all your help.